# In MySql how to design two tables with same columns but with different relationship

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have tow table **Customer** and **Partner** that share the same attributes(columns names) but they don't have the same relationships.

the relationships are as follows:

Only the customer has a account.

A customer can have only one partner.

A client has a profession.

A partner has a profession.

**My solutions**:

**1**

[image]

Create a single table (User) that contains all the attributes with a foreign key (`customer_id`) to reference the related customer for a partner,
So:

A Customer is a User with (`account_id`) `NOT NULL`  and (`Customer_id`) `NULL`
and a Partner is a User with (`account_id`) `NULL` and (`Customer_id`) `NOT NULL`.

**2**

[image]

Create two separate tables for both Customer and Partner, and put a foreign key in the partner table to reference his related customer.

**3**

[image]

Create a base table contains all common attributes, and add a foreign key in both Customer and Partner Tables to reference this  table.

I want to know which approach seems correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm saying you misunderstood something. You compulsively try to combine attributes of different entities (customer, partner). What you probably want or should do is normalize data. (so you already got some keywords for further research).

A customer is something other than a partner, another entity. If you want to put all it into a table, as in solution 1, then firstly the name "User" is misleading. Second, you would have to insert an attribute that specifies the type (e.g. EntityType (Customer, Partner) and references a separate table). Your suggestion whether something is NULL or not is highly error-prone and no one else will understand (and neither will you after 3 months). If the business logic changes so that a partner gets a login, you already have a problem.

Happy learning... =)
"teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime"

Answer (score -1):

I built my model without looking at your proposed models, and I ended up with something very close to your no.2.  The only difference is that I put PartnerID as a foreign key in the Customer table.  You did the opposite.  Here it is a mater of choice, do Partners "have" Customers of the other way around?  I saw it the other way around that you did.

**For your no1**: you are trying to put application logic in the database model, I would not do that.  It is prone to problems with data integrity (ex. you end up with users with both fields == Null!).

**For your no3**: I understand you want to "isolate" the common fields, but if the values in table User are never reused anyway, I do not see the point.  You will always have 1 line for each customer and 1 line for each partner.  Might as well have it in the tables.  This is only valid if you *never* have customers and partners being the same person.

Comment: I put the CustomerID as a foreign key In the Partner table to avoid a null foreign key reference, because a Customer can be created without a partner, and a Partner must have one related Customer.  No.2 solution it's the simplest for for performing query, but I was wondering  if it's a bad practice to have two different tables with the same column name.